# MSRA (Microsoft Remote Assistance) not working on a single machine with group policy deployed

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, remote-assistance

I'm using unsolicited remote assistance offers (msra /offerra) in my network to assist users in my windows domain. The correct settings (firewall, enabling, and all the necessary rules) are deployed via group policy and have been working for years.

Among the machines on my network, there is one Windows Server 2019 VM used as remote desktop for smart working and remote access in general. Up until a few weeks ago, I was able to offer assistance to this machine too, but now I get this error:

[image]

This is what I get in event viewer:
[image]

Now, the only difference I can spot between this and the other machines I'm using msra on, is that this is a Windows Server 2019 machine and all the others are either Windows 10 or 11 clients.

I already checked several threads about registry keys and ole permissions in dcomcnfg, but nothing ever worked.

This MUST be because of a windows update (which I don't intend to remove) since I'm the only administrator on the machine and no change whatsoever was ever done to the machine in the last weeks. Only thing that happened was automatic updates, and since this machine is exposed, I must keep it updated.

Any clues?

EDIT: You might find the screenshots are quite similar to others found on google - they're actually the same, since the error is exactly the same and my windows machines are in italian so they'd be difficult for most of you to read

Comment: One [post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/unable-to-use-msra-offerra-under-windows-10-21h2/cff32af4-a80e-43a0-b8bc-c4106372b223) says the problem is with [KB5014665](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/june-23-2022-kb5014665-os-build-20348-803-preview-feebab2b-1851-4119-a531-89ca80300b10) which isn't for Windows Server 2019.